# How to use covariance matrix with sklearn.decomposition.PCA?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I am doing some PCA with Python using [sklearn.decomposition.PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) comparing the results with others software that I use seems that the module compute the PCA using the correlation matrix I would like to compute it using the covariance matrix instead, because the data of my dataset are homogeneus. Do I have to write again the procedure or is there an easy fix to use with this module?

Comment: Would a function transforming the covariance matrix to the correlation matrix help you? It certainly is possible to do that.

Comment: @AmiTavory mm actually I want to use the convarance matrix to compute the PCA not vice-versa. Thanks however.